# Datatables: filter using links outside of table

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm trying to have links outside of the table that I can use to filter a single column within the datatable. Basically, the links will be a bunch of category names and within the table I will have a hidden column that contains the category names.

This is, for the most part, what I'm trying to do.

```
<ul id="category-filter">
   <li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
</ul>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="program-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Course Prefix</th>
                            <th>Program</th>
                            <th>Degree(s)</th>
                            <th>Certificate(s)</th>
                            <th>Sample Plan</th>
                            <th>Category</th><!-- Hidden Column -->
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>...</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try anything other than creating the html? Wheres the datatables code?

Comment: At this point nothing is being pulled from a database, it's just a static table while testing it.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504608/use-search-bar-to-filter-data-in-data-table-based-on-search-string?noredirect=1#comment68443393_40504608)  Please see if you can answer this similar question.

Answer (score 2):

Look at fnFilter (http://www.datatables.net/api#fnFilter).  The 1st parameter is the thing to search for, and the second is the column you want to target. :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

  // Sometime later - filter...
  oTable.fnFilter( 'test string', 5 );
} );
```