# Use search bar to filter data in data table based on search string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, angularjs-filter

I am trying to apply a filter in a data table from input received from a search bar. I have an input field in header of my application. On entering a value in that search bar, I need the page to get redirected to 'http://localhost:1001/#/employees' page and the filtering should be applied.

Header html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner" ng-controller="getUserHeader">
        <div class="container">
     <form class="navbar-search pull-right" ng-submit="applySearch()">

                    <input id="input-search" class="search-query" name="mysearch" ng-model="mysearch" placeholder="Search">


                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Header controller :

```
myApp.controller('getUserHeader', ['$scope', 'commonServices', 'dataTable', '$rootScope', '$location', '$filter', function ($scope, commonServices, dataTable, $rootScope, $location, $filter) {
    commonServices.getReservations().then(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;
 $scope.applySearch = function () {
            alert($scope.mysearch);


        }

    });

}]);
```

I want to pass the mysearch value to the filter on data table contained in the partial view 'http://localhost:1001/#/employees'. The HTML code and controller code of that page is,

HTML :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">

    <div class="widget widget-table action-table">
    <div class="widget-header"> <i class="icon-th-list"></i>
      <h3>Employee</h3>
</div>
    <div class="widget-content  table-container" ng-controller="getEmployeesController" >

                <table ng-table="employeesList" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in $data">
                        <td data-title="'#'">
                           {{ (itemsPerPage * (pageNumber-1)) + $index+1 }}
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="'First Name'" sortable="'firstName'" filter="{ 'firstName': 'text' }">
                            {{employee.firstName}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The filtering works fine from within this page.

Controller :

```
myApp.controller('getEmployeesController', ['$scope', 'employeeServices', 'dataTable', '$window', '$timeout', '$filter', function ($scope, employeeServices, dataTable, $window, $timeout, $filter) {
    employeeServices.getEmployees().then(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;
  });
```

Data Table is configured in App.js file :

```
myApp.factory('dataTable', ['$filter', 'ngTableParams', function($filter, ngTableParams) {

    var factoryDefinition = {
      render: function($scope, config, componentId, data) {

        if(!config) config ={};
        var config = angular.extend({}, {page:1, count:10}, config)

        $scope[componentId] = new ngTableParams(config, {
            total: data.length, // length of data
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                // organize filter as $filter understand it (graph object)
                var filters = {};
                angular.forEach(params.filter(), function (val, key) {
                    var filter = filters;
                    var parts = key.split('.');
                    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                        if (i != parts.length - 1) {
                            filter[parts[i]] = {};
                            filter = filter[parts[i]];
                        }
                        else {
                            filter[parts[i]] = val;
                        }
                    }
                });
                // use build-in angular filter
                var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                        $filter('filter')(data, filters) :
                        data;
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                        $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                        data;
                params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                $scope.pageNumber = params.page();
                $scope.itemsPerPage = params.count();
            }
        }); 


      }
    }

    return factoryDefinition;
  }
]);
```

So basically I have different controllers in both the header and in the partial view. I want to enter a string on search bar in header and on enter click, it should redirect to the partial view and apply the filter on the data table contained inside.

How am I supposed to achieve this? Sadly I was not able to create a plunker for this.

This is how the values are passed to App.js file while a filter is applied from within the partial view (https://i.imgsafe.org/595e6265b7.jpg). I added this so that you can see how the custom data table works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi mate can you create a plunker out of your code that would easy the process'

Comment: I will try to, but I failed in previous attempts. I am unable to link all the code  which are in different files....

Comment: I tried it but sadly I cant get it running. Do you need any other information including screenshot of the app so youll get a clear picture?

Comment: @Angular_10 : So I guess Plunker is required to proceed? :/

Comment: see the problem is I'm not a big fan of ng-table or any other 3 rd party ng-directives and I have never used them. So to create from scratch it would be difficult for anyone !

Comment: True.... Sorry for the trouble. I will try to figure out plunker

Comment: @Angular_10 . Hello mate. Does this come under your field of expertise?
I have set a bounty for this one and was not getting enough attention. Pls have a check if you have the time... Thank you :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396959/downloaded-document-getting-corrupted-using-blob-method-in-angularjs